# Rewrite rule is not working in htaccess for a similar page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have multiple queries for the single page. To make the URL clean I have used htaccess but for the similar only the first rule is working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ eventlist.php?i=$1  # 1st rule works
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ eventlist.php?c=$1  # 2nd rule doesn't work
```

The first rule is getting me perfect results but the second one does not get me any result .

Comment: Both rewrite rules have the same regex pattern, the first rule will catch everything. Update your question with sample urls that you want distributed to each rule.

Comment: http://localhost/10times/eventlist?i=education-training    this url has to be converted to http://localhost/10times/education-training

Comment: http://localhost/10times/eventlist?c=india has to be converted to http://localhost/10times/india

Answer (score 0):

Both of your rules are the same, the second doesn't work because the first already rewrites the URL. Besides that, the rule itself is not logic.

Your example will do the following:

- *domain.com/123* will point to *eventlist.php?i=123*

If you would move the second rule to be first, the following would happen:

- *domain.com/123* will point to *eventlist.php?c=123*

How do you know wich one brought you to eventlist?

A working, and more logic solution would be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^i-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ eventlist.php?i=$1
RewriteRule ^c-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ eventlist.php?c=$1
```

This way **domain.com/i-123** will point to **eventlist.php?i=123**. This is just an example, you would be better of using something like **domain.com/event-123/**

***Edit:***

Based on your comment, you want to keep only one URL and point it to either a country or industry. This is wat you do in your case:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ eventlist.php?ic=$1
```

In your PHP file, you should check your database / data if `$_GET['ic']` is a country or industry. Based on the result of your check you can display the events needed.

Really important in this case: do NOT forget that each industry or country has to be unique.

Comment: actually i represents industry here and c represents country here .  the page eventlist has to display data by industry when requested and the same page eventlist has to display data by country when requested .  what would be the best solution

Comment: That's exactly what I explained in my answer. Ill try to explain it even more simple. Will update my answer directly, just a second.

Comment: but the results from i is different is comes from $_GET['i']   and for c is different if comes from  $_GET['c']   , so still will it work in this case

Comment: You clearly lack knowledge of PHP.  Post your eventlist.php so I can help you out.

Comment: i believe one should not come up to any comments on any one else before knowing the complete things ....      anyhow leave it , never mind .. i am ready to explain the complete thing .  on the index page i have 2 lists ,  1 is the industries list and 2 is the country list . i want the list of events on the event list page by industry if it is asked from the industry list ,  and on the same page if it is called by the country list ..

Comment: Well sad to hear that, but I don't think anyone would even be so kind to explain it as much as I just did, I even offered to look into your code. The server can't guess if you want to see a country or industry. Your rewrite rule will point EVERY url to evenlist.php?i=$1 right now..

Comment: To make it clear for you... if you go to domain.com/blablabla it will point to eventlist.php?i=blablabla even if that industry doesn't exist.

Comment: so what is the alternate for that